# Is there a way to fake DateTime.now() in a Flutter test?

Tags: testing, time, flutter

I can pass in a time to my widget, but my widget is supposed to be instantiating the time in itself, not receiving a DateTime from a parent widget.

Answer (score 3):

The clock package: https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/clock/latest/clock/clock-library.html lets you inject a fake clock into the test.

Comment: You can also use things like mockito

Comment: Using mockito to use a fake time is less straightforward since you can't directly stub `DateTime.now()`.

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly mockito would work...

Answer (score 3):

As Mary said, a very neat way is to use [the clock package](https://pub.dev/packages/clock), which is maintained by the Dart team.

Normal usage:

```dart
import 'package:clock/clock.dart';

void main() {
  // prints current date and time
  print(clock.now());
}
```

Overriding the current time:

```dart
import 'package:clock/clock.dart';

void main() {
  withClock(
    Clock.fixed(DateTime(2000)),
    () {
      // always prints 2000-01-01 00:00:00.
      print(clock.now());
    },
  );
}
```

I wrote about this in more detail [on my blog](https://iiro.dev/controlling-time-with-package-clock/).

Just note that for widget tests, you need to wrap `pumpWidget`, `pump` and `expect` in the `withClock` callback - only wrapping `pumpWidget` does not work.

Answer (score 2):

```
extension CustomizableDateTime on DateTime {
  static DateTime customTime;
  static DateTime get current {
    if (customTime != null)
      return customTime;
    else
      return DateTime.now();
  }
}
```

Just use `CustomizableDateTime.current` in the production code. You can modify the returned value in tests like that: `CustomizableDateTime.customTime = DateTime.parse("1969-07-20 20:18:04");`. There is no need to use third party libraries.

Comment: Since it's relying on a static variable it can add hidden dependencies between tests. While running in parallel if one test changes the mock value and then it get's changed immediately by another one, it's going to fail the test.