# How to test code that uses DateTime.now in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I have this class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AgeText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String dateOfBirth;

  const AgeText({Key key, @required this.dateOfBirth}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final age = _calculateAge();
    return Text(age.toString());
  }

  int _calculateAge() {
    final dateOfBirthDate = DateTime.parse(dateOfBirth);
    final difference = DateTime.now().difference(dateOfBirthDate);
    final age = difference.inDays / 365;

    return age.floor();
  }
}
```

I'd like to test that it produces the correct age when a date of birth is passed into it. What is the best way to do this in Flutter?

---

**SOLUTION**: For those interested, here's the solution using @Günter Zöchbauer's suggestion of the [clock](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/clock) package.

My widget class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:clock/clock.dart';

class AgeText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String dateOfBirth;
  final Clock clock;

  const AgeText({Key key, @required this.dateOfBirth, this.clock = const Clock()}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final age = _calculateAge();
    return Text(age.toString());
  }

  int _calculateAge() {
    final dateOfBirthDate = DateTime.parse(dateOfBirth);
    final difference = clock.now().difference(dateOfBirthDate);
    final age = difference.inDays / 365;

    return age.floor();
  }
}
```

and my test class:

```
import 'package:clock/clock.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/age.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets("shows age 30 when date of birth is 30 years ago", (WidgetTester tester) async {
    final mockClock = Clock.fixed(DateTime(2000, 01, 01));
    final testableWidget = MaterialApp(
      home: AgeText(
        dateOfBirth: "1970-01-01T00:00:00",
        clock: mockClock,
      ),
    );

    await tester.pumpWidget(testableWidget);

    expect(find.text("30"), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you use the [clock](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/clock) package for code depending on `DateTime.now()` you can easily mock it.

Other than creating a custom wrapper around `DateTime.now()`, I don't think there is a better way than what the `clock` package provides.

Answer (score 27):

As Günter said, [the clock package](https://pub.dev/packages/clock), maintained by the Dart team, provides a very neat way to achieve this.

Normal usage:

```dart
import 'package:clock/clock.dart';

void main() {
  // prints current date and time
  print(clock.now());
}
```

Overriding the current time:

```dart
import 'package:clock/clock.dart';

void main() {
  withClock(
    Clock.fixed(DateTime(2000)),
    () {
      // always prints 2000-01-01 00:00:00.
      print(clock.now());
    },
  );
}
```

I wrote about this in more detail [on my blog](https://iiro.dev/controlling-time-with-package-clock/).

For widget tests, you need to wrap `pumpWidget`, `pump` and `expect` in the `withClock` callback.

Comment: Excellent article.

Comment: I went through your blog (nice read btw) and implemented the clock package but i found it hard to use and unpredictable i made my own similar to @Adam Smaka answer below and its just a lot easier to use

Comment: How do that along blocTest ?

Comment: Do you mean we have to use clock.now() instead of DateTime.now() in the source code?

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63073876/2235274 implement extension on DateTime.

```
extension CustomizableDateTime on DateTime {
  static DateTime _customTime;
  static DateTime get current {
    return _customTime ?? DateTime.now();
  }

  static set customTime(DateTime customTime) {
    _customTime = customTime;
  }
}
```

Then just use `CustomizableDateTime.current` in the production code. You can modify the returned value in tests like that: `CustomizableDateTime.customTime = DateTime.parse("1969-07-20 20:18:04");`. There is no need to use third party libraries.

Comment: More concisely:  `return customTime ?? DateTime.now();`

Comment: This looks like a code smell. 
It is a bad practice to modify code for testing purposes.
Also, customTime may result in bugs.
You can just wrap DateTime.now() in a class with only a function that returns current. Then in the tests mock this class to return whatever you need to.

Comment: @loshkin I agree. Also I prefer now to inject the DateTime to any function / class instead of getting it directly from inside.

Comment: @AdamSmaka An additional advantage if time injection is the ability in production code to have multiple things occur at precisely "the same moment," which is not possible if each thing gets its own slightly different time for "now."